# LG L9 P769 screen inverted

Tags: rom, stock-android, lg

I used fastboot and then installed a stock ROM (D20H) on a LG L9 P769 , but when the phone installed the ROM and rebooted EVERYTHING was mirrored on the screen from right to left. Is this a kernel problem, how can I fix it. The phone is not mine, I really need help fixing it fast. :(

Touch screen barely works. Nothing works like it is supposed to.

You can't tell from the picture, but the recycle icon with the two arrows is color inverted too. It is supposed to be yellow right. Well mine is Blue. So was the lying android with the exclamation mark above it.

[image]
<sup>(click image for larger variant)</sup>

Comment: I managed to reverse it again, I flashed JB with fastboot for P769 and now I am stuck on the LG logo. I believe this is what is called a boot loop. How to fix that?

Comment: Probably wrong kernel if you can't get passed the lg logo.